# Route PropertyChanged Event from static ObservableCollection to non-static wrapper class

Tags: data-binding, static, uwp-xaml, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection, which is filled in a Background thread, to a charting Control in the UI.
Therefore i have a static class "Core", which have a member "DataState". This DataState class owns the ObservableCollection "SensorData", which is filled in the aforementioned Background Task.

As there is no possibility to do UWP XAML Binding for static properties i wrote a wrapper class "DataWrapper" which is nonstatic and refers to the static Core.DataState.SensorData-object.

Here's some of my Code:

Core.cs:

```
public static partial class Core
{
    private static DataState m_DataState;
    public static DataState DataState
    {
        get
        {
            return m_DataState;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                m_DataState = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DataState.cs:

```
public class DataState
{
    private ObservableCollection<SensorData> m_SensorData = new ObservableCollection<SensorData>();
    public ObservableCollection<SensorData> SensorData
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SensorData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                m_SensorData = value;
        }
    }
```

DataWrapper.cs:

```
public class DataWrapper
{
    public ObservableCollection<SensorData> SensorData
    {
        get
        {
            return Core.DataState.SensorData;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Charting:LineSeries Name="MySeries" Title="Title" IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataWrapper.SensorData}"></Charting:LineSeries>
```

where X and Y are the variables contained in the SensorData-Object.

So, if i wait to Show the Charting-Control until there's some data in the ObservableCollection this data is nicely plotted into my Control. But after that recently added data is not plotted anymore.

Therefore i am looking for a way to route the PropertyChanged-Event from Core.DataState.SensorData somehow to DataWrapper.SensorData. Is there any possibility to do this?

Is the structure of this Problem clear to you? I think my descriptions sounds a bit confusing...

Thank you in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Anyone an Idea? Did i describe the Problem too confusingly?

Comment: [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/94f636ba-95eb-4af1-89dc-598d591cb272/route-propertychangedevent-from-static-observablecollection-to-nonstatic-wrapper-class?forum=wpdevelop) is a same issue you can reference.